# Nucleo32 USART2 no data on pin

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, usart, nucleo

I am using a Nucleo32L011 dev board that has a STM32L011KT6 chip on it. I want to receive data on the chip's LPUART1 and send it forward via USART2.  I have set the coresponding GPIOs to the appropriate AF, configured the USART parameters and enabled the clock.  LPUART1 works fine in blocking mode. I can transmit and receive data on the board pins.  Using a USB-ttl, i connected to the TX pin of USART2, and no data comes out. The TDR register is written when i try to send the data, but nothing comes out of the pin.

GPIO and USART configuration:

```
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

__HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE()
;
__HAL_RCC_USART2_CLK_ENABLE();

GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_9;           //PA9 USART2 TX    --- D1 board
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_USART2;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_10;        //PA10 UART2 RX      ---D0 board
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF4_USART2;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART2_IRQn, 0, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART2_IRQn);

__HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE()
;
__HAL_RCC_LPUART1_CLK_ENABLE();

GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_2;  //PA2    LP_UART1_TX
GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_AF_PP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLUP;
GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_HIGH;
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF6_LPUART1;

HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_3;       //PA3 LP_UART1_RX
GPIO_InitStruct.Alternate = GPIO_AF6_LPUART1;
HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(LPUART1_IRQn, 0, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(LPUART1_IRQn);


__HAL_RCC_USART2_CLK_ENABLE();

UartHandle_2.Instance = USART2;
UartHandle_2.Init.BaudRate = 115200; 
UartHandle_2.Init.WordLength = USART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
UartHandle_2.Init.StopBits = USART_STOPBITS_1;
UartHandle_2.Init.Parity = USART_PARITY_NONE;
UartHandle_2.Init.Mode = USART_MODE_TX_RX;

if (HAL_USART_DeInit(&UartHandle_2) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
}

if (HAL_USART_Init(&UartHandle_2) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
}

__HAL_RCC_LPUART1_CLK_ENABLE();

UartHandle.Instance = LPUART1;
UartHandle.Init.BaudRate = 9600; 
UartHandle.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_9B; //UART_WORDLENGTH_9B;
UartHandle.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
UartHandle.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_EVEN;
UartHandle.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;

if (HAL_UART_Init(&UartHandle) != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
}



/**
* @brief  System Clock Configuration
*         The system Clock is configured as follow :
*            System Clock source            = MSI
*            SYSCLK(Hz)                     = 2000000
*            HCLK(Hz)                       = 2000000
*            AHB Prescaler                  = 1
*            APB1 Prescaler                 = 1
*            APB2 Prescaler                 = 1
*            Flash Latency(WS)              = 0
*            Main regulator output voltage  = Scale3 mode
* @retval None
*/

    void SystemClock_Config(void) {
        RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = { 0 };
        RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = { 0 };

    /* Enable MSI Oscillator */
    RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_5;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0x00;
    RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
    if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK) {
        /* Initialization Error */
        while (1)
            ;
    }

    /* Select MSI as system clock source and configure the HCLK, PCLK1 and PCLK2
     clocks dividers */
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = (RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK
            | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1 | RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2);
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
    RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
    if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK) {
        /* Initialization Error */
        while (1)
            ;
    }
    /* Enable Power Control clock */
    __HAL_RCC_PWR_CLK_ENABLE();

    /* The voltage scaling allows optimizing the power consumption when the device is
     clocked below the maximum system frequency, to update the voltage scaling value
     regarding system frequency refer to product datasheet.  */
    __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE3);
}
```

If i call:

```
if (HAL_USART_Transmit(&UartHandle_2, (uint8_t*) g_SerialNumber, 8, 0xff)
        != HAL_OK) {
    Error_Handler();
}
```

nothing appears on the USB-ttl.

Comment: what do you mean by USB TTL ? Do you refer to the virtual com port provided by the STLink probe ? Just in case: did you check the port setup (baudrate and other parameters) on PC side ? Another point: did you check that the GPIOs for USART are correct ? it is linked to the model of Nucleo

Comment: The GPIOs for the USART are correct. I used a USBttl to connect to the USART pins available on the board (pins D1 and D0 on my board).  Yes, the communication parameters(baud, parity, word length) are correct

Comment: why not using the virtual com port provided by STLink ? This way, you don't need any additional hardware with the possible associated issues

Comment: Using the virtual com port, USART2 works, but mapped on other GPIOs.   PA2 and PA3 can be used for LPUART1 or can be mapped USART2 (alternate function).   Both work with the virtual com port from STLink.    If i map USART2 to PA9 and PA10, GPIOs that have pins on my board (Pins D0 and D1), it doesn't work.  My configuration needs LPUART1 mappeded to PA2 and PA3, and USART2 to PA9 and PA10

Comment: do you have a logic analyser / UART spy ?

Comment: or may be just a scope

Comment: I will get a logic analyser later, for now, the USB-ttl is all i have. To be honest, I don't expect there to be a signal on the pin. My suspicion is that the board I have needs a specific solder or something to use the USART on those pins. I'm new to using these kind of devBoards, but that's my line of thinking for now

Comment: Now I remember that on my Nucleo you have to change a solder bridge in order to route one of the USART to the external connectors (Morpho connector). Might be the same issue on yours

Comment: In the datasheet, under Hardware layout and configuration, the pins I am trying to use have a note that reads " Only one USART is available and it is shared between Arduino Nano and VCP. The selection is done by
remapping (no hardware configuration to change)."